# why it is not working to validate only numbers, not going to true condition

Tags: javascript, validation

The following function is for validating numbers.

```
function strictlynumber(obj)
{ 
    var numbers=/^[0-9]+$/;
    if (obj!=numbers)
    {
        alert("please enter numbers only");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Because of syntax. For example `if (!numbers.test(obj))` assuming obj is a string - read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: [(MDN) JavaScript Guide - Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You have to test the value against the `Regex`. You can not simply compare the value passed with `Regex` object in that way. Try the following:

```js
function strictlynumber(obj) { 
  var numbers=/^[0-9]+$/; 
  if (!numbers.test(obj)) { 
    alert("please enter numbers only"); 
    return false; 
  } 
  return true;
}
console.log(strictlynumber(5))
```

Comment: I'd like to up vote this but a little explanation of why OP's code doesn't work would be nice.

Comment: @Touffy, I have added some description. Hope that helps OP. Thanks for reminding me to add some description.

Comment: Already in the comments. Question should be closed as "a typo-type question"

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that the question shows very little effort, but it might be ignorance rather than a typo, so maybe useful for other people (coming from Perl maybe?) who try using == on regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexObject.test(obj)` method,

In your code `obj!=numbers` , is a test of equality , it will always return true.

Modified code :

```
function strictlynumber(obj)
{ 
    var numbers=/^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!numbers.test(obj))
    {
        alert("please enter numbers only");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please follow the below link for more info on Regular Expression :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Already in the comments. Question should be closed as "a typo-type question"

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `obj!=numbers` is comparing the regular expression `/^[0-9]+$/` to `obj`

You need to execute the regular expression against the input such as.

```
function strictlynumber(obj)
{ 
    var numbers=/^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!obj.match(numbers))
    {
        alert("please enter numbers only");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here we use the [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method of a `string` prototype.

Comment: Already in the comments. Question should be closed as "a typo-type question"